# ANCOVA sensitivity to large variation existing in only one of the groups

Tags: ancova, pre-post-comparison

I plan to run ANCOVA to test the effect of diet intervention across 3 groups. I have before and after intervention measurements and use before measurements as covariate ( `lm(After ~ Group + Before, data = data)`). However, for one of the variables, I can see a notable effect in one group but ancova results are not significant and I think it might be because there is huge variation among measurements of the other group.

How can I compare these groups while taking into account this variation in only one group?
My first guess is: subgroup analysis. Maybe bootstrapping is not an option here as I have only 40 samples per group. Wilcoxon test might not be appropriate as not sure how to take into account the baseline covariate.

Comment: Unequal variances is one of the points where AN(C)OVA indeed has issues. You may want to take a look at "robust ANCOVA" methods, but be aware that these by construction may test a different null hypothesis than AN(C)OVA.

Comment: Pre-post designs only work in very special cases, because of the confounding with time trends and treatment.  What about your study makes a pre-post design yield valid estimates?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Re justifications for pre-post design, I have used anova to test if there are significant differences in pre measurements and I the groups didnt differ in terms of that. Also, the experiment itself is a clinical trial which is supposed to be random in recruitment of participants. Are these points acceptable for this purpose?